# Writing graph object to dimacs file format

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have created a graph object using the networkx library with the following code.

```
import networkx as nx

#Convert snap dataset to graph object
g = nx.read_edgelist('com-amazon.ungraph.txt',create_using=nx.Graph(),nodetype = int)
print(nx.info(g))
```

However I need to write the graph object to a dimacs file format which I believe networkx's functions do not include. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The specification described on http://prolland.free.fr/works/research/dsat/dimacs.html is pretty simple, so you can just do something like this:

```py
g = nx.house_x_graph() # stand-in graph since we don't have your data
dimacs_filename = "mygraph.dimacs" 

with open(dimacs_filename, "w") as f:
    # write the header
    f.write("p EDGE {} {}\n".format(g.number_of_nodes(), g.number_of_edges()))
    # now write all edges
    for u, v in g.edges():
        f.write("e {} {}\n".format(u, v))
```

this generates the file "mygraph.dimacs":

```
p EDGE 5 8
e 0 1
e 0 2
e 0 3
e 1 2
e 1 3
e 2 3
e 2 4
e 3 4
```

Comment: The description of the graph file format is available on this website: https://www.diag.uniroma1.it//challenge9/format.shtml#graph